# Update static map in memory based on kafka event?

Tags: java, caching, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, in-memory

My application is deployed on multiple nodes and more nodes can be added dynamically.
I have a static java map to store some configs by ID. I receive an event on kafka topic whenever those configs are `added`/`updated`/`deleted`. I have one consumer group and I need to update this static map on all the nodes.

For reference, I prefer to not use any other DB for this - distributed/in-memory, etc,.

Kindly suggest the best approach to do this - with or without using DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a different `group.id` on each node; only one consumer is a group can consume from a single partition.

Comment: this solution works! I also looked at spring cloud bus implementation and apparently they are doing the same thing internally.